# Nested collections in Hazelcast IMap

Tags: java, hazelcast, serializable, in-memory-database, hazelcast-imap

I have a hazelcast instance and I am getting a map from it.

```
IMap<Object,Object> cache= hazelCastInstance.getMap(collectionName);
```

I want to store a nested collection (e.g. List < List< Definition > >) into it.

**Definition** => Class (This implements serializable)

```
cache.set(cacheKey, object, ttl,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**cacheKey** => unique key

**object** => nested collection

**ttl** => time to live

I am getting an exception: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$SubList

I am using hazelcast for the first time. Does anyone have any idea why is that?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the ArrayList$Sublist not being serializable. It can be resolved by replacing your code by something like this:

```
cache.set(cacheKey, new ArrayList(objects), ttl, SECONDS)
```

Now you got rid of the inner class that is causing problems. The content of the sublist will be copied into a normal ArrayList and there are no problems serializing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was basic mistake. The nested list was created using list.subList() method. That was the reason it was failing.